# React Native - Move code from render() into a different function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to React native. I have a noob question related to moving code away from the main function which is render() and put the code into a different function.

Let's say I have the following code:-

```
render() {
 return (
   <View>

   <Modal
     animationType={"fade"}
     transparent={true}
     visible={this.state.signUpPopUpVisible}
     onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}>
      {/* Other modal codes */}
   </Modal>

  <View style={styles.mainView}>
      {/* Other mainView codes */}
  </View>

  </View>
);

}
```

How can I move the whole code

```
   <Modal
     animationType={"fade"}
     transparent={true}
     visible={this.state.signUpPopUpVisible}
     onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}>
      {/* Other modal codes */}
   </Modal>
```

into a different function and call it in the render()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try doing it this way,

```
showModal = () => {
    return (<Modal
      animationType={"fade"}
      transparent={true}
      visible={this.state.signUpPopUpVisible}
      onRequestClose={() => { alert("Modal has been closed.") } }>
      {/* Other modal codes */}
    </Modal>);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.showModal()}
        <View style={styles.mainView}>
          {/* Other mainView codes */}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: `this.showModal` is not a function call. It's just the function prototype.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to return your object within another function the same as you did in render.

Example:

```
yourFunction(){
  return(
    <View></View>
  );
}
```

Sample of your code:

```
render() {
 return (
   <View>
      {this._renderModal()}
      <View style={styles.mainView}>
          {this._renderMainViewCode()}/* Other mainView codes */
      </View>
  </View>
 );
}

_renderModal(){
  return(
    <Modal
      animationType={"fade"}
      transparent={true}
      visible={this.state.signUpPopUpVisible}
      onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}>
       {this._renderModalCode()}/* Other modal codes */
    </Modal>
  );
}

_renderModalCode(){
  return(
    <Text>This is the modals code</Text>
  );
}

_renderMainViewCode(){
  return(
    <Text>This is the main views code</Text>
  );
}
```